# Можно ли сделать что бы nginx вне докера работал с php-fpm в докере?

Tags: php, nginx, php-nginx

Есть сервер, на нем крутятся nginx и php5.
Задача поменять php на 7 версию.
Но что бы не удалять старый, не переустанвливать и тд, решили Php7 сделать в докере и пробросить порт 9000, а в nginx переписать конфиги на такие:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    #было fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #стало fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Но после этого сайт начал выдавать ошибку `No input file specified.`

Подскажите кто знает как лучше

Comment: 1. Включите `error_log куда-будете-логировать debug` (режим дебага) 2. затем выполните проблемный HTTP запрос 3. покажите логи